# error en conexion a base de datos PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Saludos estoy intentando establecer la conexión a mi base de datos con codificación orientada a objetos  y me genera un error que no logro resolver:

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\php\conexion.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php(4): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\php\conexion.php on line 10

    <?php 
  $arrOptions = array(
   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
);

try {

   $this->conexion= new PDO('mysql:db=lacorotera;host=localhost', 'root', '', $arrOptions);
   return $this->conexion;
        
} catch (Exception $e) {

   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " producido en la línea: " . $e->getLine();

}finally{

}
?>
```

Comment: Yo no veo a la propiedad conexión declarada en tu clase ¿dónde esta declarada como propiedad?

Comment: Ese código que expones esta dentro de alguna clase?

Comment: Si no está dentro de una clase, sustituye $this->conexion simplemente por $conexion

Comment: En efecto @BetaM le faltaba la declaración de la clase, gracias por responder igual a ti Omar

Comment: @Apalazon si encontraste la solución a tu problema te invito a que la publiques

Comment: Perfecto, modificaré la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Forma correcta de establecer una conexion mediante una clase, con código orientado a objetos

```
<?php 
class Conexion{

   protected $conexion;

   public function Conexion(){
  $arrOptions = array(
   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
);

try {

   $this->conexion= new PDO('mysql:db=lacorotera;host=localhost', 'root', '', $arrOptions);
   return $this->conexion;
        
} catch (Exception $e) {

   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " producido en la línea: " . $e->getLine();

}finally{

  }
 }
}
?>
```